# Blocking overwriting of objects in Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore I have a collection with several documents, with structure like

```
users: [
  1234: {
    foo: 'bar'
  }
]
```

In old version of our app (that we've since fixed, but there are still many users using it), there's a piece of code executing

```
firestoreInstance.collection('users').doc(1234).set({});
```

because of an old bug.

It's overwriting the whole object, so it becomes

```
users: [
  1234: {
  }
]
```

I've tried blocking this specific overwrite with following security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  function objectIsEmpty() {
    return request.resource.data.size() == 0;
  }

  match /users/{userId=**} {
    allow read;
    allow write: if !objectIsNotEmpty();
  }
}
}
```

but the overwrites are still happening. I've tried the same thing with
`allow write: if false;` and it didn't help.

According to [Customize Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data?authuser=0):

> There are three operations for writes in Cloud Firestore: **create**, update, and delete. These correspond to the **set()**, add(), update(), remove(), and transaction() methods in the client libraries. For your convenience the write operation allows all of these.

I imagined not allowing `write` with empty object (by disallowing writes with `request.resource.data.size() == 0`) would not allow the `set({})` code from being executed.

What's curious, same piece of code, only with **`update` instead of `set`** is blocked properly and the object isn't overwritten.

Is there something wrong with my rule? Is there another way to block any write operation with an empty object?

Comment: If you think the documentation is wrong, or the implementation of the documentation is wrong, please file a bug report.  It certainly seems that your rule should disallow that set().  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson, I opened a bug then!

Comment: Your code seams correct but I wonder just try without function like : `allow write: if request.resource.data.size() == 0`

Comment: Hey @HakanC thanks for the suggestion, but that one doesn't work either. I even tried with `allow write: if false;` and could still execute the operation.